# Is onProviderEnabled only called if listener registered for that provider?

Tags: android, listener, android-location

The question is simple: **For a location listener's onProviderEnabled() method to be called when a specific provider is enabled, must that listener have already requested updates from that same provider?**

For example, if you register for location updates with location manager from the network provider:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0,
                0, locationListener);
```

The listener has an onProviderEnabled() method:

```
@Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.d(TAG, provider + " provider enabled"); }
```

If I now turned on the GPS location provider, will onProviderEnabled be called?

From what I've experienced, no it is not called, unless the location listener was also registered to receive updates from the GPS provider. If it is supposed to be like this, then one would have to register with both the GPS and Network provider in order be notified that it was enabled.

**Is it ok to register for updates from a location provider that is not yet enabled?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For a location listener's onProviderEnabled() method to be called when a specific provider is enabled, must that listener have already requested updates from that same provider?

Yes, you need to register for a provider to be able to receive a callback from it.

It's the action of registering with one provider, that informs that provider that a listener exists. If you don't register with it, there is now way for it to know that a listener exists.

> Is it ok to register for updates from a location provider that is not yet enabled?

Yes.

Comment: Thanks. The whole reason why I'm checking is because I thought maybe registering for a location provider that isn't enabled was breaking something in my app. Rarely, my location providers seem to get stuck, and not provide any new locations. The strange thing is google maps still works fine. However, in my app, the location listeners register fine with both providers, but no new locations are found until I restart the phone! Restarting/uninstalling/clearing data on the app doesn't solve the issue. When this happens, GPS stops working for any apps, and GPSLocationProvider keeps the phone awake.

Comment: I must tell you that I've never faced something similar that wasn't resulting from a bug in my app. You said first that Google maps stills work, and then that it stopped for all apps. Can you clarify? Are you registering the listener in a  `Service` or `Thread` class? This can lead to similar situations.

Comment: Network location works in google maps but GPS doesn't show up in google maps either (as if it's turned off). The GPS being stuck off might be a separate issue though. I've made a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13849748/network-provider-stops-providing-updates