# Network provider stops providing updates

Tags: android, location, listener, location-provider

I have noticed that rarely (every few days), my app stops receiving new location updates.

The location listener is registered with both network and GPS providers. The GPS provider is off so any location updates come from the network provider. Every few days or so, I notice the location is old and not updating. From my debug log I can see that the location listener is being registered with location manager but there are just no new locations being found. onLocationChanged() is not called.

The strange thing is, Google Maps has no problem getting a new network location. Restarting/reinstalling/clearing data on the app does not solve the issue. The only thing that solves it is to restart the phone.

This has happened on 3 different devices (2 ICS, 1 JB).

Similar problem but not worded very well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594932/network-provider-not-providing-updated-locations).

Comment: I believe that a working network connection is required for network provider to return a new location. Did you try browsing internet to check it, when the error occured?

Comment: Yes, there was working internet in all cases.